# Run archive node to store states for the last N months only

Tags: go-ethereum, clients

We have to get the state at specific blocks within the past 3 months. For this we have to launch the archive node, as current `fast-sync` node stores only last 64 Blocks.

- is it possible to launch `geth` or any other client with `archive-sync` option, but not by starting from the genesis block, but let say only for N last blocks?
- for the running `fast-sync` node, is it possible to refetch and store the states for N last blocks?
- any other solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erigon might be a good fit (6 day sync for full archive), also has pruning:
https://github.com/ledgerwatch/erigon